# Unable to assign different variable types according to condition in same class in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, class, if-statement, variables

I need to declaring variables according to this `isCandidateResult == false or true`

here `isCandidateResult == false` than in `FilterData` Class in need to assign

```
var jobType: [String] = []    
var jobRole: String = ""
```

and `isCandidateResult == true`

```
var jobType: String = ""   
var jobRole: [String] = []
```

but how i am unable to

**code:**  to achieve my goal i have tried like this code but.. with this code i am getting below errors

```
 import UIKit
 var isCandidateResult: Bool = false

if isCandidateResult == false{//Error: Statements are not allowed at the top level
class FilterData {

var jobType: [String] = []    
var jobRole: String = ""

init(jobType: [String], jobRole: String) {
    self.jobType = jobType
    self.jobRole = jobRole
}
}
}
else{

class FilterData {

var jobType: String = ""   
var jobRole: [String] = []

init(jobType: String, jobRole: [String]) {
    self.jobType = jobType
    self.jobRole = jobRole
}
}
}



class FilterViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var filterTableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var subFilterTableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var filterTitle: UILabel!

if isCandidateResult == false{
var filterData = FilterData(jobType: [], jobRole: "")//Cannot find 'FilterData' in scope
}
elase{
var filterData = FilterData(jobType: "", jobRole: [])
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}
}
```

ERRORs:
1)

> Statements are not allowed at the top level
> 2)
> Cannot find 'FilterData' in scope

Comment: You can't. Is your issue about using the same UITableView but with different kind of elements? What would be the code of cellForRowAtIndexPath then? The better solution would be to use a Model for the UITableView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how it should be done.

Instead, create a model which could be initialized with a job type and roles, or with a job role and types, a model for the `UITableView`. That way, you don't need to care about if it's job type & roles or the other one. You populate the model only. And let the tableview manage its own data. It doesn't need to know what's inside.

```
struct FilterTableViewModel {

    let title: String
    let elements: [String]

    init(jobType: String, roles: [String]) {
        title = jobType
        elements = roles
    }

    init(jobRole: String, types: [String]) {
        title = jobRole
        elements = types
    }
}
```

And:

```
class FilterViewController: UIViewController {
    var filterData: [FilterTableViewModel] = []
}
```